# PostgreSQL doesn't sort according to `LC_COLLATE=C` even though DB is configured to

Tags: postgresql, collation

**UPDATE**: after `initdb`ing with `libc` local provider (instead of `icu`), it started to work fine. Is this a bug or ICU simply assigns something else to "C"?

I created a database explicitly with:

```
encoding = 'utf8'
lc_collate = 'C'
lc_ctype = 'en_US.utf8'
```

And `show lc_collate` shows `C`. But when comparing strings, it's something else:

```
select 'B' > 'a';
> true

select 'B' collate "C" > 'a' collate "C";
> false
```

How come? The values in my columns are also sorted incorrectly unless I explicitly tell it to use "C".

*Environment:* MacOS, PGv15. My cluster was initialized with ICU enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Q: ICU simply assigns something else to "C"*

"C" as a locale name refers to a built-in locale in libc, but indeed it means nothing  to ICU.

If you had passed "C" in the `ICU_LOCALE` argument to `CREATE DATABASE` it would have been essentially ignored, and interpreted as "unspecified language".

The purpose of passing something in the `lc_collate` argument of a database whose locale provider is `ICU` is to set the environment variable `LC_COLLATE` to that value. It might be useful for code in extensions, especially in PL languages, that call functions like [strcoll](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcoll.html) or [strxfrm](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strxfrm.html).
But string comparisons initiated by Postgres itself with the default ICU collation **will not use** what's in the `lc_collate` database parameter. This is why setting `lc_collate` to `C` has no effect in your new database.

To create a database with C as the default collation, in a initialized cluster with ICU as the default, it must be a `libc` database and created from `template0` with a statement like:

```
CREATE DATABASE db
 TEMPLATE='template0'
 LC_COLLATE='C'
 LC_CTYPE='en_US.utf8'
 LOCALE_PROVIDER='libc';
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to find out which `LOCALE_PROVIDER` is used? Simple `show LOCALE_PROVIDER` doesn't show it..

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev: `select datlocprovider from pg_database where datname=current_database();`